# HTML email align text

Tags: html, email, html-email

I am trying to align a part of text to the right and the other part to the left in an HTML mail but in Outlook the `float` doesn't work. So basically I am looking for `float` CSS in Outlook. I know it sounds pretty creepy and `text-align` or `align=""` didn't work. Any suggestions?

```
<td>
   <span style="text-align:left; float:left;">
       First part
   </span>
   <span style="text-align:right; float:right;">
       Second part
   </span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Honestly, if you're doing an HTML email I'd stick to using tables. Not all CSS selectors are available in all email clients and you'll drive yourself mad trying to do it any other way. HTML emails are like the web 5 years ago.

There are a couple of good documents on the subject:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

http://www.emailology.org/

For your example:

```html
<td>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td align="left">First part</td>
      <td align="right">Second part</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
```

It's horrible but unfortunately it's still the best way.

Answer (score 7):

Use (*shudder*) layout tables.

Outlook's support for styling of email is so awful that there isn't any other way.

There is a [24 ways article](http://24ways.org/2009/rock-solid-html-emails) with some general advice for writing HTML formatted email.

Comment: So there is no way to align one part right and one part left?

Comment: Lotus notes is the worst I find but it seems to be almost extinct which is good. Why they use Word as Outlooks rending engine I have no idea.

Comment: @user1299846 — That isn't what I said.

Comment: not forget to mention, lots of users around that only view plaintexts

Answer (score 2):

```
<p align="right">My right content</p>
```

It should do the trick as it is HTML1.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I wanted to center three images in the footer of my email. I got it to work like this.

```
            <div style="display:inline-flex; width:100%;">
                <img style="width: 15%; height:fit-content; margin: 0 7.5%;" src="https://example.com/employment-ontario.png" alt='img-logo0'/>
                <img style="width: 15%; height:fit-content; margin: auto 7.5%;" src="https://example.com/canada-logo.png" alt='img-logo1'/>
                <img style="width: 15%; height:fit-content;  margin: auto 7.5%;" src="https://example.com/ontario-govt.png" alt='img-logo2'/> 
            </div>
```

the image with `margin: 0 7.5%` **is the largest of all the images** (if you want to imitate `align-items: center` set the other two to images to `margin: auto 7.5%`, they will automatically center your images.

**Note:** In this example 7.5% is for only one side of your container, so total margin on the left and right will be 15%. for one img, giving a total of 45% used.

Sum of mine is 90% , but you get the idea.

Image of what it looks like below.

[image]

Comment: actually it does. 
This  aligns items vertically and provides a solution for spacing content based off of width %. 

It also aligns content to the left and right, if someone copy and pasted this code and changed the <img> attribute to <div>, though verbose, would do the trick.

Comment: My bad. I have removed the auto comment.