# SAS Dashboard embedded in Email

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I am using GKPI to create a SPEEDOMETER dashboard as shown below. How can I send this Speedometer embedded (not as an attachment) in an e-mail.

```
PROC GKPI
mode=raised;
 speedometer actual = &Percentage 
 bounds=(0 .60 .80 1) / target = .85
 colors=(red yellow green)
 activecolors=(red yellow green)
 format = "percent8.0"
 lfont=(f="Albany AMT/bold" height=.5cm)
 label = "STL RFID Utilization";
run;
quit;
```

Comment: Are you generating a .png file or some other image file?  What format are you using to send the email? I haven't had much luck in trying to embed images in HTML email. Maybe rtf email would work. Suggest you add code showing how you are sending the email.

Comment: I provide a method to do what you are attempting here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25270596/214994  . Beware - it is quite involved...

Comment: I finally used this and it worked: