# text-align = center not working

Tags: fonts, html-table, html-email

I am practising html email and trying to center text. but its not working. also I have a doubt this is not working because I am using style tag inside of the font tag. I have tested my code in validator.w3.org  and its passed. Is anything wrong with this code. Please help me to align text to center.

```html
Doctype is : <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <font style="font-family: verdana; font-size:10px; font-weight: bold; text-align: right;"><i>
"We are such stuff as dream are made on, and our little life is rounded with a sleep"  William Shakespeare</i>
  </font>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This post might help...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989657/html-email-align-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's your corrected code:

```html
<table width="100%">
<tr>
  <td style="text-align: right;"> 
    <font style="font-family: verdana; font-size:10px; font-weight: bold;"><i>
"We are such stuff as dream are made on, and our little life is rounded with a sleep"  William Shakespeare</i>
  </font>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry , I have tested the code by making the text-align to right to see if it work. I forgot to change it back to center before posting it.

Comment: Thank you Gabriel. So text-align now works when I insert in the <td style = "text-align : center;">. like you mention in your code.  Do you know why it don't work when we put inside of the font ,styl e tag.

Comment: "The text-align property in CSS is used for aligning the inner content of a **block** element." (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align/) <font> is an inline element, hence the text-align property isn't supposed to be used.

Comment: Please mark as answered if it solved your problem. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use align="left" attribute instead of text-align

Comment: Not supported in HTML5