# Using additional css classes in email markup

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

In outlook htm email additional classes are ignored.

In this example when I render and email the following html. The resulting markup is as below.

**The final statement does not align right.** `Class2 RgtTx`

```
.RgtTx {
  text-align: right !important;
}

<td class="RgtTx"></td>
<td class="RgtTx Class2"></td>
<td class="Class2 RgtTx"></td>
```

I am unsure but expect this isn't isolated to Outlook.

Is there a workaroud or fix for this using css **without changing the html**?

---

#### This is not a duplicate qustion

- I don't want to know how to align text in an email.
- I want to know why additional classes do not work in emails and how to handle this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML email align text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989657/html-email-align-text)

Comment: @thebrownkid no, its about why the `style` element doesn't work -- a perfectly valid question.

Comment: CSS support in email clients is such a dark art! Long shot, but do compound selectors (e.g. `.Class2.RgtTx`) work?

Comment: @HiddenHobbes thanks, but already been down the different selector lines. I suspect more complex selectors are even less likely to be supported.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right, get the feeling that you're out of luck on this one.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, email requires inline styles--otherwise it will work sparingly (check [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/style-element/style-in-body/) for support among clients). Try using a CSS inliner like https://inliner.cm/. It takes this:

```
<style>
  .RgtTx {
  text-align: right !important;
}
</style>
<td class="RgtTx"></td>
<td class="RgtTx Class2"></td>
<td class="Class2 RgtTx"></td>
```

and turns it into:

```
<style>
  .RgtTx {
  text-align: right !important;
}
</style>
<td class="RgtTx" style="text-align:right !important;" ></td>
<td class="RgtTx Class2" style="text-align:right !important;" ></td>
<td class="Class2 RgtTx" style="text-align:right !important;" ></td>
```

which should work.

Comment: Thanks for this I am aware this is prefered however I cannot edit the html. It is from prerendered markup.

Comment: @Obsidian oh sorry, I was not aware of that. Unfortunately, the `style` element is not supported in many common email clients, including Gmail. Check it out here: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/style-element/style-in-body/

Comment: Ok thanks. I was afraid is was simply not supported.

Comment: Gmail supports style in head. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/style-element/style-in-head/

Comment: @Syfer I think it’s still best practice to have inline styles—some clients (not necessarily gmail) don’t support <style>

Comment: I agree best practice is to do inline but 95% of email clients now support media query. Am not saying do only styles in head was just pointing out that Gmail supports style in head.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook ignores tags with `!important`.

Outlook ignores `@media` queries. So one thing you can do is place values in a query to influence other email clients.

You can also create an Outlook-specific style sheet to influence Outlook 2007-2016 Desktop without interfering with modern email clients:

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<style type="text/css">
  body {font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important; font-size: 14px;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

This article covers other shortcomings with Outlook:

- https://litmus.com/community/learning/8-outlook-overview

Since you're unwilling to use in-line styles, you're going to be limited to how much you can influence Outlook. As an example, if you're resizing images, Outlook will ignore in-head style values for size and display the image in it's actual size.

Good luck.